# pyperclip module in python 3.4 not in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5, linux-mint, pyperclip

I am completely new to programming and Linux OS.

In my Linux machine, I edited my bashrc so that when I type python, it calls python3. I have python 3.4 and python 3.5.2 installed. Recently, I install this module pyperclip using pip3 install.

My problem is when at python 3.5.2, the pyperclip module couldn't be found, I couldn't import it at terminal. When at python 3.4, I get to import the module.

Being completely new to Linux, I have no idea how to access the "pyperclip" module via python 3.5.2

I bought this book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python." and the projects are really interesting.

Is it advisable to have more than one version of Python in my machine? Can I just use only one? How to I import pyperclip module in python 3.5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Terminal.

```
pip3 install

pip3 install setuptools

pip3 install pyperclip
```

However you may need to have downloaded the zip pyperclip module first. Mine was in my Downloads directory on my Mac before I ran the previous three pip lines in Terminal.